# Recoding 150+ categorical variables in R

Tags: r, hashmap, plyr, recode

I have a files with a bunch of cities (so far, 183) and none of them have counties mapped to them, which is something I need. For re-coding categorical variables I usually use plyr's rename() function, but I don't want to write a messy nasty piece of code to recode all these cities. I have also been learning a bit of python lately, and this problem sounded a little like a dictionary/hash table problem. I would like to learn to do something a bit more programmatic, if possible.

As a first shot I went ahead and created a .csv that has the name of each city in one column and its county in another. I was hoping to join this together somehow with the file I need so that things could be mapped over. Some minimal code to show what I mean:

```
#key_file: 
LocalityName <- c('Addy', 'Burien', 'Newman Lake', 'Seattle', 'Tacoma')
CountyName <- c('Stevens', 'King', 'Spokane', 'King', 'Pierce')
key <- cbind.data.frame(LocalityName, CountyName)

#real_file:
LocalityName <- c('Seattle', 'Seattle', 'Tacoma', 'Seattle', 'Newman Lake')
CountyName <- rep(NA, length(LocalityName))
Extra_Example_Col <- c('Y', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N')
real <- cbind.data.frame(LocalityName, CountyName, Extra_Example_Col)
```

I tried using join() in plyr but couldn't get it to work (I can update with my code if this is a right track for me to follow, not sure). I know about the sqldf package too but since I'm also just learning SQL for the first time now as well, am not sure if this is a type of join? My brain thinks of this as a "one to many" kind of mapping.

I think trying to learn all these other languages right now is confusing me a bit, but it's giving me some ideas of how to try things. My preferred solution would be R idiomatic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use `merge` from base R, or `join` from plyr. For example:

```
# Key_file: 
LocalityName <- c('Addy', 'Burien', 'Newman Lake', 'Seattle', 'Tacoma')
CountyName <- c('Stevens', 'King', 'Spokane', 'King', 'Pierce')
key <- cbind.data.frame(LocalityName, CountyName)

# Real_file:
LocalityName <- c('Seattle', 'Seattle', 'Tacoma', 'Seattle', 'Newman Lake')
CountyName <- rep(NA, length(LocalityName))
Extra_Example_Col <- c('Y', 'Y', 'N', 'N', 'N')
real <- cbind.data.frame(LocalityName, CountyName, Extra_Example_Col)

# merge
merge(real, key, by = "LocalityName")
##   LocalityName CountyName.x Extra_Example_Col CountyName.y
## 1  Newman Lake           NA                 N      Spokane
## 2      Seattle           NA                 Y         King
## 3      Seattle           NA                 Y         King
## 4      Seattle           NA                 N         King
## 5       Tacoma           NA                 N       Pierce

# plyr::join
join(real, key, by = "LocalityName")
##   LocalityName CountyName Extra_Example_Col CountyName
## 1      Seattle         NA                 Y       King
## 2      Seattle         NA                 Y       King
## 3       Tacoma         NA                 N     Pierce
## 4      Seattle         NA                 N       King
## 5  Newman Lake         NA                 N    Spokane
```

Note that with `merge`, you get `CountyName.x` and `CountyName.y` because the same column exists in both data sets. With `join`, you have two columns named `CountyName`. You probably don't want to initialize the `CountyName` column in the `real` data.frame. For example, have `real <- cbind.data.frame(LocalityName, Extra_Example_Col)`, or `real[["CountyName"]] <- NULL` to drop that column before merging.

Comment: Wow, I was making that way too complicated. I did just that in join but let the error that I got throw me into thinking it wasn't the right method. Thanks - I'll try to figure out the little bug

Comment: I also suggest looking at the help files for the functions when you run into problems (`?join` or `?merge`).

Answer (score 3):

for mapping you could use `merge`.
For example:

```
merge(real, key, by='LocalityName', all.x=TRUE)
```

Comment: simplicity at it's finest!  +1

Answer (score 0):

```
library(data.table)

key  <- as.data.table(key)
real <- as.data.table(real)

## If necessary, make sure your values are strings, not factors, etc
key[, LocalityName := as.character(LocalityName)]
real[, LocalityName := as.character(LocalityName)]

## Set the keys, this is for joining.
##  not to be confused with your object named "key"
setkey(key, LocalityName)
setkey(real, LocalityName)

## Ensure you have a character and not a logical 
key[, CountyName := as.character(CountyName)]
real[, CountyName := as.character(CountyName)]

## The i.X notation indicates to take the value 
##   from the column inside the [brackets]
real[key, CountyName := i.CountyName]

real
#    LocalityName CountyName Extra_Example_Col
# 1:  Newman Lake    Spokane                 N
# 2:      Seattle       King                 Y
# 3:      Seattle       King                 Y
# 4:      Seattle       King                 N
# 5:       Tacoma     Pierce                 N
```